# IE8 Choking on CSS3 -- Avoiding it not reading rest of the file

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have the following css:

```
.mcRow input.mcCheckbox {
    display:none;
}

.mcRow input.mcCheckbox + label {
    background: url('/media/img/pt/dhtml/mc_off.gif') no-repeat;
    height: 19px;
    width: 19px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: auto;
}

.mcRow input.mcCheckbox:checked + label {
    background: url('/media/img/pt/dhtml/mc_on.gif') no-repeat;
}​

.mcRow input.mcCheckbox.checked + label {
    background: url('/media/img/pt/dhtml/mc_on.gif') no-repeat;
}​
```

Since IE8 doesn't play well with CSS3, I've included a backup .checked class that's toggled with jQuery. I want my custom checkboxes to display even if JS is broken, thus why I want to keep the :checked pseudo-selector included in CSS3.

The above order doesn't play well in IE 8. It seems it ignores everything after the :checked statement.

```
.mcRow input.mcCheckbox + label {
        background: url('/media/img/pt/dhtml/mc_off.gif') no-repeat;
        height: 19px;
        width: 19px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        width: auto;
    }

    .mcRow input.mcCheckbox.checked + label {
        background: url('/media/img/pt/dhtml/mc_on.gif') no-repeat;
    }
​
    .mcRow input.mcCheckbox:checked + label {
        background: url('/media/img/pt/dhtml/mc_on.gif') no-repeat;
    }​
```

works just fine. I'm afraid of adding this to a file and someone adding other CSS after this statement, not knowing none of it will be read in IE8. :( What should I do?

Comment: Technically, it ignores a rule if it doesn't understand its selector. It shouldn't completely ignore the rest of the file unless the rest of the file has nothing but CSS3 selectors that IE8 doesn't understand. If that still happens then your CSS probably has some sort of encoding issue.

Comment: It is clearly ignoring the rest of the file. I can move ANY css below :checked and nothing is read in IE8. What "encoding" would do this?

Comment: @bobber205 - This is not the behavior i experience, nor is it the behavior of anyone else I can find with google.  It ignores the entire statement, but it should continue processing after that.  Unless, there is an error in the structure of the css (missing brackets or such).  If you take out the + label, is everything still ignored afterwards?  Another thing to do is run the css through the W3's CSS validator, and see if there is any illegal CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could of course just place a comment in the CSS.

However, a better method may be to simply use IE conditional comments to not include that code in IE < 9.

Comment: The above link seems to be for hmtl comments. I need a CSS solution.

Comment: @bobber205 - There is no css solution.  You have to split your css up into different files, the ones that apply to IE and the ones that apply to everyone else.  Then you use conditional comments in the html to load the IE css when running on ie, in addition to the normal css.

Comment: @bobber205 - Note: I'm not saying that I agree with your assumption that IE8 ignores the rest of the file, in my experience it doesn't.  However, my point is that if such a situation were in fact true then you would use conditional comments to work around it.